# store query data in variables

Tags: c#

I would like to know how I could loop over the query below and store values in different variable the table below shows us the data which is output in the query and would lie to store each of the values in str1,str2,str3

```
sortByColumn |   numberOfRow  |  coloumnsInExcel
8            |    10          |       10

var queryAD1 = (from m in configurationData.AsEnumerable()
                              where m.Field<String>("QuestionStartText") == question && m.Field<String>("slideNo") == Convert.ToString(slideNumber)
                             group m by m.Field<String>("slideNo") into A123Group
                             select new {
                                 sortByColumn = A123Group.Select(sorted => sorted.Field<String>("SortByColumn")).Distinct(),
                                 numberOfRow = A123Group.Select(sorted => sorted.Field<String>("NoOfRows")).Distinct(),
                                 coloumnsInExcel = A123Group.Select(sorted => sorted.Field<String>("ColumnInExcel")).Distinct(),
                             });
```

Comment: Your query always returns only one row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
foreach (var query in queryAD1)
{
    str1 = query.sortByColumn;
    str2 = query.numberOfRow;
    str3 = query.coloumnsInExcel;

    //do something with the variables...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try with

```
queryAD1.sortByColumn
queryAD1.numberOfRow
queryAD1.columnsInExcel
```